# Lodash How to filter out of a array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, lodash

I need to filter specific objects out of a array.
i got multiple array's like this in a json file.

```
 "functies":["zandbak", "voetbal", "petanque", "speeltoestellen", "basketbal"],
```

We need the possibility to filter on each element of the array for each object in the json file.

Javascript code

```js
ready(function () {

    var App = {
        "init": function () {
            this.URLSPEEL = './data/speelterrein.json'; // Cache the url with random users in variable URLRANDOMUSERME
            this.loadDataSpeel(); // Load SPEEL Data
        },
        "loadDataSpeel": function () {
            //1. Create a XMLHttpRequest object (Send to and load data from a WebAPI)
            var xhr = typeof XMLHttpRequest != undefined
                ? new XMLHttpRequest()
                : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            //2. Declare the type of the response
            xhr.responseType = 'json';
            //3. Listen to the changes in states within the connection
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                switch (xhr.readyState) {
                    case 0:
                        console.log('UNSENT');
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        console.log('OPENED');
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        console.log('HEADERS RECEIVED');
                        console.log(this.getAllResponseHeaders());
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        console.log('LOADING');
                        break;
                    case 4:
                    default:
                        console.log('LOADED');
                        //If status equals 200 then everything is ok else nok
                        if (xhr.status == 200) {
                            console.log('OK');
                            //Get the received data --> response

                            var data = (!xhr.responseType) ? JSON.parse(xhr.response) : xhr.response;
                            var speelterreinen = data.speelterreinen, n = speelterreinen.length, speelterrein = null;
                            var tempString_2 = "";
                          

                            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                                speelterrein = speelterreinen[i];
                                console.log(speelterrein.length);
                                tempString_2 += '<div id="speelterrein_id" class="card blue-grey darken-1 z-depth-2">';
                                tempString_2 += '<div class="card-content white-text">';
                                tempString_2 += '<span class="card-title" >' + speelterrein.naam;
                                tempString_2 += '</span>';
                                tempString_2 += '<h5>Functies</h5><p>' + speelterrein.functies;
                                tempString_2 += '<div class="card-action"><a target="_blank" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="' + speelterrein.plaats;
                                tempString_2 += '">Locatie</a>';
                                tempString_2 += '</div></div></div>';
                                console.log(speelterrein.functies);

                                document.getElementById("speelterrein_id").innerHTML = tempString_2;

                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log(Error(xhr.status));
                        }
                        break;
                }

            };
            //4. Open the connection or tunnel to the resource on the url
            xhr.open('GET', this.URLSPEEL, true);
            //5. Make the request to the specified resource
            xhr.send(null);
        }
    };
    App.init();
});
```

Example json file

```js
{"speelterreinen":[
  {
    "naam": "Sint-Baafskouterpark",
    "functies": ["avontuurlijk spelen", "zandbak", "speeltoestellen"],
    "coördinaten": "51.0568047,3.7551683",
    "gemeente": "Sint-Amandsberg"
  },
  {
    "naam": "Wasstraat speelterrein",
    "functies":["zandbak", "voetbal", "petanque", "speeltoestellen", "basketbal"],
    
    "coördinaten": "51.0553976,3.7442046",
    "gemeente": "Sint-Amandsberg"
  },
  {
    "naam": "Azaleastraat buurtpark",
    "functies":["zandbak", "petanque", "speeltoestellen", "basketbal"]
    "coördinaten": "51.0600225,3.7498565",
    "gemeente": "Sint-Amandsberg"
  },
```

Comment: You question is unclear. Please reframe it

Comment: So, at the end, given, say, "petanque" you want a list of places where you can play petanque?

Comment: @georg thats indeed the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, given a keyword, this will create a list of "speelterreinen" objects whose "functies" contain this keyword:

lodash:

```
places = _.filter(data.speelterreinen, function(x) { return _.includes(x.functies, keyword)} );
```

ES6:

```
places = data.speelterreinen.filter(x => x.functies.includes(keyword))
```

Complete example:

```js
let data = {
    "speelterreinen": [
        {
            "naam": "Sint-Baafskouterpark",
            "functies": ["avontuurlijk spelen", "zandbak", "speeltoestellen"],
            "coördinaten": "51.0568047,3.7551683",
            "gemeente": "Sint-Amandsberg"
        },
        {
            "naam": "Wasstraat speelterrein",
            "functies": ["zandbak", "voetbal", "petanque", "speeltoestellen", "basketbal"],

            "coördinaten": "51.0553976,3.7442046",
            "gemeente": "Sint-Amandsberg"
        },
        {
            "naam": "Azaleastraat buurtpark",
            "functies": ["zandbak", "petanque", "speeltoestellen", "basketbal"],
            "coördinaten": "51.0600225,3.7498565",
            "gemeente": "Sint-Amandsberg"
        },
    ]
};

let keyword = 'petanque';
let petanque_places = data.speelterreinen.filter(x => x.functies.includes(keyword));

console.log(petanque_places)
```

Comment: To verify it works can i =    console.log(places); ?

Comment: @mathiasvansele: posted a complete example

Comment: U sir, u are a hero <3